# How to get rid of whitespace when printing documents?

Tags: pdf, printing, whitespace, libreoffice, removing-whitespace

A PDF with lecture slides contains huge whitespaces (ca. 50% of actual slide dimensions on each border). How can I get rid of those in a printout?

NOTE: Printer settings are **not** useful. Zooming is not possible, as this immediately cuts into one side of the slides and toggling automatic centering does not solve this issue either. Need document level solution!

Is there a function for this in common word processing programs? I have imported the PDF into LibreOffice Draw. The slides are imported as images, but I do not want to rescale 60 images on 30 pages by hand:

[image]

Source: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kyros/courses/418/Lectures/lecture.2010f.02.pdf

Comment: You can't remove it during the printing process, because the printer driver knows nothing about white space or whether you want it or not. It knows that you sent data to it that should be sent on to the printer itself. If you don't want the whitespace in the PDF, edit the PDF itself to remove it, or write code that restructures the PDF. However, you've said that the slides are imported as images, which means that you can't just restructure the PDF itself. You'll need to extract the image from the PDF and use a graphics editor to crop the images.

Comment: @KenWhite: I have found a workaround. Out of sheer interest: What do you mean by writing code that restructures PDFs? Can PDFs be edited the same way e.g. as a Word document (without write protection)?

Comment: Yes, the PDF structure is well documented. There are also code libraries available (find them in your favorite search engine) that allow editing the files directly.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that! Thanks for this bit

Comment: **Solution**: There are online tools for cropping PDFs. I used https://www.sejda.com/de/crop-pdf